DbUpdateConcurrencyException in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web app
In my ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC web app, this is the DbContext in which I have overridden SaveChangesAsync() to assign a new cart to any new added user:
using Egost.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Egost.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Egost.Data;

public class EgostContext(DbContextOptions<EgostContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<User>(options)
{
    public DbSet<EditHistory> EditHistories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CartProduct> CartProducts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PromoCode> PromoCodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OrderProduct> OrderProducts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReturnOrder> ReturnOrders { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ReturnProduct> ReturnProducts { get; set; }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // Add new cart for new users
        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries<User>()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);

        foreach (var entry in entries.ToList())
        {
            var user = entry.Entity;

            if (user.Cart == null)
            {
                Cart cart = new();
                Carts.Add(cart);
                user.Cart = cart;
                Users.Update(user);
            }
        }

        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}

And this is the User model class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Egost.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Egost.Areas.Identity.Data;

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData] public string Name { get; set; }
    [PersonalData] public DateOnly DOB { get; set; }
    [PersonalData][AllowedValues("Male", "Female")][MaxLength(6)] public string? Gender { get; set; }
    [PersonalData] public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> WishList { get; set; }
    public Cart? Cart { get; set; }
    [Required][DataType(DataType.DateTime)] public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)] public DateTime? DeletedDateTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EditHistory> EditsHistory { get; set; }
}

This is the Program.cs file:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Egost.Data;
using Egost.Areas.Identity.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); 
var config = builder.Configuration;

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<EgostContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<EgostContext>();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddGoogle(options =>
   {
       IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
       config.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
       options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
       options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
   })
   .AddFacebook(options =>
   {
       IConfigurationSection FBAuthNSection =
       config.GetSection("Authentication:Facebook");
       options.AppId = FBAuthNSection["AppId"];
       options.AppSecret = FBAuthNSection["AppSecret"];
   })
   .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
   {
       microsoftOptions.ClientId = config["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
       microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = config["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
   });

var app = builder.Build();

using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<EgostContext>();
    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

    // Apply migrations
    dbContext.Database.Migrate();

    // Seed roles
    await SeedRolesAsync(roleManager);

    // Seed super user
    await SeedSuperUserAsync(userManager, config);
}

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Store}/{action=Index}");

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

static async Task SeedRolesAsync(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
{
    string[] roleNames = { "Admin", "Moderator", "Transporter" };

    foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
    {
        if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName))
        {
            await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
        }
    }
}

static async Task SeedSuperUserAsync(UserManager<User> userManager, IConfiguration config)
{
    IConfigurationSection superUserData = config.GetSection("SuperUser");
    var superUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(superUserData["Email"]);

    if (superUser == null)
    {
        superUser = new User { 
            Name = superUserData["UserName"],
            UserName = superUserData["UserName"],
            Email = superUserData["Email"],
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            Gender = "Male"
        };

        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(superUser, superUserData["Password"]);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(superUser, "Admin");
        }
    }
}

And now I got this error in EgostContext on the line:
return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);


Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

The error happens when ever any user is added to the database either with Super User seeding or with normal registration.

Try remove Users.Update(user); and test again.
